# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::getInstance()

Tags: php, pdo

i checked all other questions with same title but i couldnt solve. i trying to learn PDO thing :D i think only a real php master can solve this problem. and can advice a webpage for learn pdo.

Index.PHP

```
require_once 'core.php';
DB::getInstance();
```

CORE.PHP

```
session_start();

$GLOBALS['yapilandirma']= array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'kullanici_adi' => 'root',
        'sifre' => '',
        'db' => 'mmogezgini'
    ),
    'hatirla' => array(
        'cerez_adi' => 'hash',
        'cerez_bitis_suresi' => 604800
    ),
    'oturum' => array(
        'oturum_adi' => 'kullanici'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once $class . '.php';   
});

require_once 'Sterilize.php';

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")
```

Yapilandirma.php

```
class Yapilandirma{
    public static function get($yol = null){
        if($yol){
            $yapilandirma = $GLOBALS['yapilandirma'];
            $yol = explode('/',$yol);
            print_r($yol);

            foreach($yol as $bit){
                if(isset($yapilandirma[$bit])) {
                    $yapilandirma = $yapilandirma[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $yapilandirma;
        }

        return false;
    }   
}
```

DB.php

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
    $_query, 
    $_hata = false,
    $_sonuclar,
    $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Yapilandirma::get('mysql/host') .';dbname=' . Yapilandirma::get('mysql/db'), Yapilandirma::get('mysql/kullanici_adi'), Yapilandirma::get('mysql/sifre'));
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }
    }
        public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }


}
```

Comment: Are these files all in the same directory?

Comment: yes in same directory but i see now i used require in another page then i should write file directory for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *all files are in the same folder*, then this `autolader` should work:

**Core.php:**

```
function autoloader($className) {
    $filename = realpath(__DIR__) . '/' . $className . '.php';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        require_once($filename);
    } else {
        trigger_error("$filename not found");
    }

    return true;
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . '\autoloader');
```

You now should be able to call `DB::getInstance();` from index.php. If class is not loaded correctly, you will see an error in your php error log.

Comment: Problem Solved it was wrong filename/path 
it was that
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
 require_once  $class . '.php'; 
});

i changed to that and solved xD
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
 require_once 'tema/parca/' . $class . '.php'; 
});
and i hate who gives direct - negative point why you guys doing that i trying to learn something i will help others when i learn.

Comment: @user3018898 Good news! Try not to hardcode you paths like `tema/parca/`. You can use `realpath(__DIR__)`, for example, to return real path of your current directory. Or you can define a global constant with application root path in your index.php and use relative path afterwards. Please accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: @user3018898 I think down voting had more to do with formatting, than with the question itself...